# Create a JUnit that fail if getInstnace() not synchronized in Java Spring implemation of singelton

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, asynchronous, junit

I was given a task during a job intreview to implement a toy Singelton database and a user controller that make use of that database by using Spring dependencies injection.
I came out with this version:

Singelton DB

```
package SingeltonDBVersion2;

import GlobalSetting.User;

public class SingeltonDB {
    private static DBconnImpl db = null;
    private static SingeltonDB singalDb = null;

    private SingeltonDB(String username, String password) {
        db = new DBconnImpl();
    }

    public synchronized static SingeltonDB getInstance(String username,
            String password) throws Exception {

        if (db != null) {
            return singalDb;
        }
        System.out.println("The database is now open");
        singalDb = new SingeltonDB(username, password);
        db.connect(username, password);
        System.out.println("The database was connected");
        singalDb.create("table1");
        return singalDb;
    }

    public void create(String tableName) throws Exception {
        db.create(tableName);
    }

    public User query(String tableName, int rowID) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return null;
        }
        return (db.query(tableName, rowID));
    }

    public void update(String tableName, User user) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return;
        }
        db.update(tableName, user);
    }

}
```

UserContorller

```
package SingeltonDBVersion2;

import GlobalSetting.IUserContorller;
import GlobalSetting.User;

/****************************************************************************
 * This is class is an implementation of a UserContorller for the version with
 * Spring, because here we use inversion of control. The UserContorller
 * constructor takes the an object of SingeltonDB which we are passing using
 * Spring Dependency Injection in our UnitTests
 *****************************************************************************/
public class UserContorller implements IUserContorller {
    SingeltonDB db;

    public UserContorller(SingeltonDB db) throws Exception {
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void createTable(String table) throws Exception {
        db.create(table);

    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(String table, int id, String name, int age)
            throws Exception {

        db.update(table, new User(id, name, age));
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String table, int id) throws Exception {

        return db.query(table, id);
    }

}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="MyUserContorller" class="SingeltonDBVersion2.UserContorller">
        <constructor-arg ref="MySingeltonDB" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="MySingeltonDB" class="SingeltonDBVersion2.SingeltonDB"
        factory-method="getInstance">
        <constructor-arg value="MyAccount" />
        <constructor-arg value="123" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I can use it in this way:

```
        ApplicationContext contex = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        UserContorller user1 = (UserContorller) contex.getBean("MyUserContorller");
        saveUser("table1", 1, Mike, 44); //add user with id 1 and age of 44
```

Now, I was asked to write a test (say a Junit) that will fail iff the SingeltonDB's getinstance() method is not synchronized...
I don't really know how to do that...

Can someone help in offering a soultion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all the singleton beans get instantiated as and when you create context. So avoid that in your case like:

```
<bean id="MyUserContorller" class="SingeltonDBVersion2.UserContorller" lazy-init="true">
 ....
<bean id="MySingeltonDB" class="SingeltonDBVersion2.SingeltonDB" factory-method="getInstance" lazy-init="true">
```

Now create Multiple threads like below:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
     private ApplicationContext context;
     private int hashCode;
     public MyThread(ApplicationContext context) {
         this.context = context;
     }
     public void run() {
         hashCode = System.identityHashCode(context.getBean("MySingeltonDB"));
     }
     public int getHashCode() { 
         return hashCode;
     }
}
```

Now create multiple instances of thread and start them all together and Assert on hashcode form each and every thread for non equality. If you get equal, its your test going to be failed and what you want.

Comment: Thanks thats a nice way to handle it, however I have a problem... wrote it a seperate message below.

Answer (score -1):

almas shaikh, this is the code I wrote:

```
package Tests;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



public class SingeltonDBVersion2TestSynch {

    static ApplicationContext Context;

    @Test
    public void testSynch() throws Exception {

        int num = 100;

        Context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(num);
        MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new MyThread(Context, startSignal, doneSignal);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i].start();
        }
        startSignal.countDown();
        doneSignal.await();
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(threads[i].getHashCode());
        }
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private int hashCode;
    CountDownLatch startSignal;
    CountDownLatch doneSignal;

    public MyThread(ApplicationContext context, CountDownLatch startSignal,
            CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
        this.context = context;
        this.startSignal = startSignal;
        this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            startSignal.await();
            hashCode = System
                    .identityHashCode(context.getBean("MySingeltonDB"));
            doneSignal.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public int getHashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

I am only trying to print the hashcode for checking... but they are all have the same hashcode (I've change the spring xml and I removed the eynchronized from getInstacnec()).
myabe I've not used the right way in CountDownLacths?

Comment: Firstly, you are introducing some synchronisation by printing in your getInstance method as multiple threads will have to synchronise on the output stream. Secondly, just running a load of threads and hoping that a condition will occur is probably not going to work. If you want to show it in a test, you may have to add a sleep in getInstance() after the test for null so there is a reasonable chance than more than one thread will get to the same point.